# Can anyone point me in direction of any good MVP articles/tutorials?

Tags: c#, mvp

Trying to learn MVP pattern with C#... Does anyone know of any particularly good tutorials or articles?!

Comment: With source code to practice , Unit Tests also incuded to explain its benefits - http://www.advertisingmarket.co.uk/MVPPattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Model View Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx) by Jean-Paul Boodhoo.
2. [Model-View-Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304760.aspx) Pattern at MSDN library.

Comment: With source code to practice , Unit Tests also incuded to explain its benefits - http://www.advertisingmarket.co.uk/MVPPattern

Answer (score 1):

Read article from Martin fowler

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html